# getchar() and malloc returning good result when it shouldn't

Tags: c, malloc, getchar

Can anyone explain me why this code works perfectly?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    int c, i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't this program crash when I enter for example "aaaaaassssssssssssddddddddddddddd"? here is what I get with this input :

```
aaaaaassssssssssssddddddddddddddd
aaaaaassssssssssssddddddddddddddd
```

And I really don't get why is it so.

Comment: Appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. You were lucky.

Comment: it´s undefined behaviour, so everything can happen, including a working function. A small hint: malloc will probably not allocate only 1 Byte.

Comment: Because your program ends before the consequences of your reckless acts can assert themselves by haunting your program executions with undebuggable intermittent errors? Why *does* a broken clock show the right time twice a day?

Comment: It shouldn't have compiled. You must have at least `#include <stdio.h>` at the top; otherwise the compiler would not recognize the symbol `EOF`. You also need `#include <stdlib.h>` to make `malloc` visible.

Comment: If C did specified that the program _must_ crash, that that would be specified behavior.  C rarely defines how things should fail.  Instead it defines how code works.  When code operates outside defined conditions, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've presumably identified you're overrunning the sizeof(char) (~1 byte) block of memory you've asked malloc to give you, and you are printing a string that you have not specifically null terminated.

Either of these two things could lead to badness such as crashes but don't right now. Overrunning your allocated block of memory simply means that you are running into memory that you didn't ask malloc to give you. It could be memory malloc gave you anyway, a minimum allocation greater than 64 bytes would not be particularly surprising. Additionally since this is the only place you allocate memory in the heap you are unlikely to overwrite a memory address you use somewhere else (ie if you allocated a second string you might overrun the buffer of the first string and write into the space used for the second string). Even if you had multiple allocations your program might not crash until you tried to write to a memory address the operating system hadn't allocated to the process. Typically operating systems allocate virtual memory as pages and then a memory allocator such as malloc is used within the process to distribute that memory and request more from the operating system. You probably had several MB of read/write virtual address space already allocated to the process and wouldn't crash until you exceeded that. Were you to have tried to write to the memory that contained your code you would likely have caused a crash due to the OS protecting that from writes (or if it didn't you would crash due to garbage instructions getting executed). That's probably enough on why you didn't crash due to an overflow. I'd suggest having fun experimenting by sending it more data to see how much you can get to work correctly without it crashing, though it may vary from run to run.

Now the other place you could have crashed or gotten incorrect behavior is in printing out your string because printf assumes a null byte terminated string, that it starts at the address of the pointer and prints until it reads a byte with value 0. Since you didn't initialize the memory yourself this could have been forever. However, it terminated printing in exactly the right spot. This means that byte 'just happened' to be 0. But that's a simplification. On a 'reasonable' modern OS the kernel will zero (write 0s to) the memory that it allocates to the process to prevent leaking information from prior users of the memory. Since this is the first/only allocation you've done the memory is all shiny and clean, but had you freed memory previously malloc might reuse it and then it would have non zero values from stuff your process had written.

Now useful advice to detect these problems in future even on programs that appear to work perfectly. If you are working on Linux (on OS X you'll need to install it) I suggest running 'small' programs through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see if they produce errors. As an exercise and an easy way to learn what the output looks like where you already know the errors try it on this program. Since valgrind slows things down you may get frustrated running a 'large' program through it, but 'small' will cover most single projects (ie always run valgrind for a school project and fix the errors).

With additional information about the environment your program is running in could lead to further explanations of implementation specific behavior. ie C implementation or OS memory zeroing behavior.